# Error conPDO Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo, login

tardes o noches. Estoy trabajando en mi proyecto y al querer validar mi login me salta el siguiente enunciado:

"*Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\walker-up\servidor\validarLogin.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\walker-up\servidor\validarLogin.php(12): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\walker-up\servidor\validarLogin.php on line 12*"

A continuacion les muestro mi codigo:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require('db.php');

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pswd = $_POST['password'];

    $conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `walker-users` WHERE `email` = ':email' AND `passwd` = :pswd;");
    $query ->  bindParam(":email", $email);
    $query ->  bindParam(":pswd", $pswd);
    $query -> execute();
    $usuario = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($usuario){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario['name_user'];
        header('Location: /index.php');
    }else{
        echo 'Los Datos introducidos son erroneos.';
    }

?>
```

Mi conexion:

```
<?php

$conexion = null;
$servidor = 'localhost';
$database = 'walker-up';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

try{
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servidor.';dbname='.$database, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error:' . $e -> getMessage() . "<br/>";
    exit;
}
return $conexion;
?>
```

Y por ultimo mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si en la línea `$query = $conexion -> prepare( ... );` le quitas las comillas a `':email'`?

Comment: Pues parece que funcionó...

Comment: Es un error tan tonto que me dan ganas de borrar la pregunta, pero la dejaré como ejemplo para que los que encuentren un problema similar, puedan percatarse. Gracias de todas formas por molestarte a comentar, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Me alegra que haya servido. Creo que otros te dirán que borres la pregunta, ya que cae dentro de la categoría de cierre: *"...contiene errores tipográficos"*; no haré nada, pero si alguien te lo recomienda, tomas la decisión.

Comment: @aeportugal escribe la solucion para que se resuelva esta pregunta amigo :) yo no opino que esta pregunta debería estar guardada

Comment: @WilliamR.Vazquez o escribela tu la respuesta como lo veáis vosotros. :)